# An extra td with spacer.gif is inserted by richfaces between the tabs generated using richfaces:tabpanel

Tags: richfaces, space, html-table, tabpanel, extra

I need to create tabs and using `richfaces:tabpanel` component.

The probelm is an extra `<td>` is genearted by richfaces which contains `spacer.gif` and thus the tabs have space between them.

I tried using the `richfaces:tabpanel property headerspacing="0px";` but the space exists.

We are using `richfaces version 3.3.3.Final` and `jsf version 1.2`

## jsp:

```
 <td width="100%">
<rich:tabPanel headerSpacing="0px;">
 <rich:tab id="tab1">
 <f:facet name="label">
 <h:outputText value="Tab1"></h:outputText>
 </f:facet>
  <ui:include src="./tab1.jspx"/>
  </rich:tab>
  <rich:tab id="tab2"> 
  <f:facet name="label">
 <h:outputText value="tab2"></h:outputText>
 </f:facet>
  <ui:include src="./tab2.jspx"/>
 </rich:tab> 
 </rich:tabPanel>
 </div>
 </td>
```

## CSS:

```
.rich-tabhdr-side-border {
    border: none;   
    background-image: none;
}

.rich-tabhdr-side-cell{
    border: 1px solid #ABAA96;  
    height:23px;
    display:block;
    background:url(../images/ButtonConatinerBG.gif) repeat-x top;
    border-bottom:1px solid #A1A290;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    }

.rich-tabpanel-content {
 font-family: verdana;
font-size: 12px;
color: #000000;    
background-color:#F9F9FB; 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide those spacers with CSS:

```
.rich-tabpanel img[src="path/to/spacer.gif"] {
    display: none;
}
```